# How can I find current month name and current month number in swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, swift4

I want to know current month number as int and name as string in swift.Can anybody help me with simple codes?

Comment: This is such a poor question, lacking research and asking us to do all the work.

Answer (score 22):

```
if let monthInt = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: Date()).month {
    let monthStr = Calendar.current.monthSymbols[monthInt-1]
    print(monthInt) // 4
    print(monthStr) // April
}
```

or:

```
let monthInt = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date()) // 4
let monthStr = Calendar.current.monthSymbols[monthInt-1] // April
```

Comment: No need for the `if let`. Just do `let monthInt = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: Date()).month!`. It's safe to force-unwrap the `month` since you specifically requested that component.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree but unsafely unwrapping is almost always not necessary. Just do it safely with an extra line of code

Answer (score 10):

The Number of the current date you can get like this:

```
let monthAsNr = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date())
```

Comment: This answer actually doesnt answer to OP’s question about getting index of month and *its name*

Answer (score 7):

You can use `DateFormatter` for getting name of current month and `Calendar`'s `component` for getting index of current month

```
let currentDate = Date()

let nameFormatter = DateFormatter()
nameFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM" // format January, February, March, ...

let name = nameFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
let index = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: currentDate) // format 1, 2, 3, ...

print(name)  // April
print(index) // 4
```